# Which options are incompatible with CRF, CQP?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, x264, obs-studio

What settings should not be used when using CQP, CRF modes. I read that 2pass mode is not compatible with constant quantization modes. It is also recommended to disable adaptive quantization. Maybe just a Spatial AQ? I want to clarify which of these is true. How justified is the use of b-frames in cqp and crf modes?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There are tons of options in ffmpeg, do not expect a list of what *may be* incompatible with one or another. The main drive is "what do you want to do?". If you have no special requirement, setting a `-crf` and a `-preset` is enough for 99.9% of the cases.